# Unable to use bootstrap date picker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I was trying to add [Bootstrap date picker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) on an input area but I am unable to configure it:

I used their [demo page](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) to generate code and tried it but it seems I am missing something Please help me fixing this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="../files/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="../files/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../files/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
        </div>

<script>
    $('#sandbox-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
        startDate: "2012-01-01",
        endDate: "2015-01-01",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
        });
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also tried using this links for [css](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css) and [js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js):

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3

Comment: `http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js` returns a 404 error

Comment: Yes error in link but not working even after correct link see update

Comment: Have you tried include `jquery` `bootstrap` etc. inside the `<head>`. Looks like you are trying to call `datepicker` before including `bootstrap` library

Comment: Tried But Still not working

Comment: @user3315579 What is `#sandbox-container` ? Could you just try to call datepicker like `$('.form-control').datepicker({....`?

Comment: How about putting your datapicker method top of the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to remove `#sandbox-container` As it is not present in your code.

**Try This:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="../files/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="../files/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../files/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
        </div>

<script>
    $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
        startDate: "2012-01-01",
        endDate: "2015-01-01",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about the 404 error on the bootstrap-datepicker includes?

Answer (score 6):

Move the script include tags above your script, and remove `#sandbox-container` from your selector - it doesn't exist.  It works after that (with correct urls)...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
        startDate: "2012-01-01",
        endDate: "2015-01-01",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
</script>
```

**[jsfiddle example...](http://jsfiddle.net/T9Fyh/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the datepicker function before calling jQuery, bootstrap.js & bootstrap-datepicker.js. If you debug it you will get an exception that tells you "datepicker" is not defined.

Instead you should write :

```
    <script src="../files/js/jquery.min"></script>
    <script src="../files/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

    <script>
        $('#sandbox-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
             format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
             startDate: "2012-01-01",
             endDate: "2015-01-01",
             todayBtn: "linked",
             autoclose: true,
             todayHighlight: true
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try once again, you didn't see part of the answer before.